# How would you remotely install software on multiple Windows XP machines?

Tags: windows-xp, remote, deployment

I need to install the standalone google talk client for Windows XP.  I have the googletalk-setup.exe.  How would you go about installing this on 100+ Windows XP systems?  Is there an automated way you would do it?

I found [this info](http://www.programmerworld.net/articles/software/google_talk.php) that mentions some command line switches but I don't see a silent install option like I've seen with some other programs.

Answer (score 6):

Two methods spring to mind:

1. Windows logon script
2. [Microsoft Systems Management Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb521519(v=winembedded.51).aspx)
3. System Center

Comment: +1 for Systems Management Server and other mass-deployment-management software in that vein

Comment: +1 Note that Systems Management Server (SMS) is now called System Center Configuration Manager (SCCM) http://www.microsoft.com/systemcenter/en/us/configuration-manager/cm-overview.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Although you can put it in the login script, you may have to add logic to check for existence, so it does not install multiple times.

You could use this free tool (PS.EXE) from Sysinternals, now Microsoft, to run the setup file on remote systems without actually logging into them, or installing any client software. I would setup a network install point for googletalk-setup.exe then use the utility. It even can install to multiple systems, or an entire domain using a wildcard.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553
http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/remote-computing/psexec (utility was renamed, but usage is the same)

Comment: You assume that all 100 systems are on in this case. The OP would probably be better off making a login script with some logic in it to check for an existing install.

Answer (score 2):

I would build an MSI file and deploy it via Group Policy.

Comment: I wish this was easier, as Group Policy is probably the most ideal method.  Unfortunately, it's rather difficult to find any decent msi-building tools that let you build them quickly and visually.

Comment: @Cypher Really?  [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/download.html), [WinInstall LE](http://www.scalable.com/wininstall-le) are [just] two free, GUI apps which make MSI packaging incredibly simple.

Comment: @jscott: i found wininstall le (and most other msi packagers) to be all but useless to those who haven't memorized the .msi db structure.  having a gui is not what i meant by visual; taking a standard setup.exe and converting to .msi by simply walking through the normal install prompts and checking off a few options along the way would be my idea of a 'quick and visual' procedure.  haven't tried adv. installer - it looked more like a packaging system for software developers.  i'll give it another look.

Comment: some software programs have .msi packages available, and those that do will make deployment via group policy a snap:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816102.

Answer (score 1):

psexec is a certainly a good tool, but does not handle multiple choices when an installer has no or few command line options (when installer is close to entirely GUI).

I've seen a working kixtart script as the logon script.  It is used to load and launch other scripts according to the install sequence which may be as follows:

"logon" script executes at login.  Launches "mount" script to mount apps drive.  Launches "updater" script that looks for apps.

"updater" script launches "transfer" script that transfers apps to local directory.  "updater" then launches "install" script (unique for each app)

"install" script may be any method... batch, AutoIT, psexec.. whichever works, preferably silent and fast

"updater" logs to directory in apps drive
"logon" script logs to directory in apps drive

All of this can be done on a shoestring budget, but there is a very steep learning curve.
I know that updating at login is a great way to slow down login.  "updater" could be installed as a Scheduled Task on login and run at a more appropriate time.

By the way, does anyone have any kixtart script samples to help him out?